# Play video file being written

Tags: c#, wpf, sockets, video, video-streaming

I developed a socket based p2p system where i stream mp4 video from a client to a server. The video data are transferred using byte[].

The transfer works, however i am struggling to figure out how i could play, in continuous, a mp4 file being transferred to another PC? The PC application, that would play the file, is in WPF.

I tried using a MediaElement to play the file, being written to the disk, but for some reason it doesnt play at all. I can play it with VideoLan tho.

Any hint of where to look? I am lost from here!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you could play the file using VLC, you could try [Vlc.DotNet.Wpf](https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet)

Answer (score 0):

Its going to be different with every player. Mp4 is probably the worst possible container for this application. The container is designed to be used with random access media, such has a hard disk. The player has the ability, and sometimes requirement to seek around within the file, and not just plat start to finish. Either you need to make the protocol mp4 aware (parse the file, and download the block that will most like be needed next), or use a streamable container such as TS, or flv.

Its is also possible that the player knows the file is incomplete. The atoms sizes are encoded within the file. If the file size doest match, the combined atom sizes, the player could assume a corrupt file.If this is what is happening, you can try to pre allocate the file. it may trick the player enough to play